# repeatin: how to keep items on same line instead of having 1 line per item

Tags: python, report, odoo, rml

I am building an openerp report using OpenOffice SXW to RML conversion.

I have added a one2many field to model "product", which links to a new model "composition" made of a text field "name".

I use repeatin to list the composition items of the products "o":

```
[[repeatIn(objects,'o')]]
...
[repeatIn(o.composition,'c')]] [[c.name')]]
...
```

It works but creates a new line for each composition item. I want those items to be displayed on the same line instead of one per line.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use a 3rd parameter with repeatIn(), telling which tag you want the repeatIn creates for each element.

By default, it's  'para' (if i'm not wrong), but you can set another, such as 'td'. With this, you can set your repeatIn() inside a table (with invisible rows) with the 'td' 3rd parameter.

Hope it helps you,

Regards

Answer (score 0):

you can solve it by writing custom method in report and return string how you want. you can call it in report like.

```
 <para style="P5">
    <font color="black">[[ method_name(o.one2many_fieldName) ]]  </font>
 </para>
```

Hope it helps you !!